# Store floating point numbers in Set?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, set

In the Ruby core library, there is a very useful `Set` class. It can store any type of object.

But as you know, floating point numbers(`Float` in Ruby) have some accuracy problems. `1.2-1.0` doesn't equal `0.2`.

```
s = Set.new()
s.add(1.2-1.0)
s.add(0.2)
s.size
=> 2
```

Yes, I can use `BigDecimal` type to get precise numbers. But is it possible to give `Set` a specific comparison function so that it can endure a small error(e.g. `1e-9`)?

(I know this problem is agnostic to language. Welcome solutions in other common languages)

Comment: The semantics are problematic.  E.g., suppose that you already have `1.0` and `1.0 + 1.5e-9` in your set, with the allowed error set to `1e-9`.  Now what happens when you add `1.0 + 0.7e-9`?  Does the set go from having 2 elements to having 1?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, and I think I've found a potential solution, depending on what you want to do. Ruby uses a `Hash` under the hood to store the element of a `Set`. In Ruby, `Hash` key equality is defined by the methods `hash` and `eql?`. So if you redefine these methods in `Float` (caveat emptor!), you can make the `Set` consider reasonably close `Float`s to be equal:

```rb
class Float

  def eql?(other)
    other.is_a?(Float) && self.round(9) == other.round(9)
  end

  alias :old_hash :hash

  def hash
    self.round(9).old_hash
  end

end

s = Set.new
s.add(0.2)
s.include?(0.2)       # => true
s.include?(1.2 - 1.0) # => true
s.include?(0.2001)    # => false
```

Comment: What about two floats like `1.0000000004999999` and `1.0000000005000001`?  These two floats are as close as they could possibly be (1 ulp difference, assuming IEEE 754 and round-to-nearest).  And yet they give different results when rounding to 9 decimal places.

Comment: You're right. The problem here is not the comparison, but the `hash` method. We could easily change the comparison to `self - other < 1e-9`, but the `hash` method's job in this case is to spit the space of real numbers into discreet chunks, and I don't think that's possible without these kind of border cases. And since the convention in Ruby is that `eql?` should return true for objects that `hash` to the same value, we have to change the comparison accordingly.

Comment: "I don't think that's possible without these kind of border cases".  Agreed.  It's a hard problem to solve, in general.  My question would be why the OP is putting Floats into a Set in the first place...